# Merging the datetime ranges at the end of the day and start of the next day

Tags: scala, datetime

Here is my input data

```
case class DateRange(sd:DateTime,ed:DateTime)

val sd1 = DateTime.parse("2016-04-04T20:00:00.000Z")
val ed1 = DateTime.parse("2016-04-04T23:59:59.999Z")

val sd2 = DateTime.parse("2016-04-05T00:00:00.000Z")
val ed2 = DateTime.parse("2016-04-05T05:00:00.000Z")

val sd3 = DateTime.parse("2016-04-05T20:00:00.000Z")
val ed3 = DateTime.parse("2016-04-05T23:59:59.999Z")

val sd4 = DateTime.parse("2016-04-06T00:00:00.000Z")
val ed4 = DateTime.parse("2016-04-06T05:00:00.000Z")

val sd5 = DateTime.parse("2016-04-07T10:00:00.000Z")
val ed5 = DateTime.parse("2016-04-07T15:00:00.000Z")

val drList = List(DateRange(sd1,ed1),DateRange(sd2,ed2),DateRange(sd3,ed3),DateRange(sd4,ed4),DateRange(sd5,ed5))
```

The desired output I am looking for is

```
val res = List(DateRange(sd1,ed2),DateRange(sd3,ed4),DateRange(sd5,ed5))
```

Here the `ed1, ed3` is the end of the day and `sd1, sd3` are start of the day for the respective dates. I want to merge that kind of ranges as we can see in the desired output above.

I tried partitioning like this

```
   val result = drList.partition(x => x.sd.isEqual(x.sd.withTimeAtStartOfDay()) || x.ed.isEqual(x.ed.withTime(LocalTime.parse("23:59:59")))))
```

But not getting how to merge the result. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip to get your result :

```
val res = if(drList.size < 2 )
           {
                drList
           }
           else
           {
               drList zip drList.drop(1) map {
               case (prevRes, nexRes) =>
               if (prevRes.ed.plusMillis(1) == nexRes.sd) prevRes.copy(ed = nexRes.ed)
               else DateRange(sd1, sd1)
           }
          res.filter(x => x.sd != x.ed)
           }
```

Here sd1 is any datetime to have at the else part and filtering it out at the last.